# Loading certificate to GKE service

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

I have a GKE cluster which run a java spring boot docker image on port 80. I have exposed it as a load balancer with multiple port mapping like 80 -> 80 and 443 -> 80.

I can see both the http and https URL's under service but I can only access my service on http port but cant access on https. I am getting **"This site can’t provide a secure connection."**

I know I need to put a certificate on this load balancer to expose on https and I have a google managed cert.

My problem is I am not getting how do I install this certificate on load balancer so that I can access my application on https as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SInce you are using GKE ingress with a google managed certificate, you don't need to manually configure it in the loadbalancer, it can be done by the ingress.

In the [oficial documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs) you can verify all the steps to make it work.

There are 2 [pre-requisites](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs#prerequisites):

1. You need to own a domain
2. You should create a static ip address.

You can create a certificate using the following yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1beta2
kind: ManagedCertificate
metadata:
  name: certificate-name
spec:
  domains:
    - domain-name1
```

And create a service as NodePort to your application, for example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-name
spec:
  selector:
    key: value
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
```

And finally you can create the ingress using the example below:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-name
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: address-name
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: certificate-name
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: service-name
    servicePort: service-port
```

If you want to migrate self-certificate to google managed certificate you can follow [this steps](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs#migrating_to_google-managed_certificates_from_self-managed_certificates)